# how to iterate table <tr> dynamically in html using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

in node js i try to render table tr with iterate function but it shows unexpected token "<". check the given code snippet. in table row  tr i want it iterate dynamically.

```
module.exports = ({p}) => {
return `
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<table class="table-bordered">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Product</th>
              <th class="w-20">Price</th>
              <th class="w-20">Quantity</th>
              <th class="w-20">Total</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

**// want to iterate below <tr>**
          <tr>
              <td>${p.name}</td>
              <td>${p.price}</td>
              <td>${p.quantity}</td>
              <td>${p.price * p.quantity}</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
              <td colspan="3" class="text-right">Sub Total</td>
              <td> ${p.subTotal}</td>
          </tr>
          
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

please help me how can i overcome to solve this issue

Comment: use a template engine like handlebars, pug, or ejs. If you have not used any template engine before i prefer ejs.  -> https://ejs.co/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this :-

Map over `array of p` and produce array of `tr` for each `p`.
Then, append it to main html

```js
module.exports = ({
    ArrayOfP
}) => {
    const allTr = ArrayOfP.map(p =>(`<tr>
        <td>${p.name}</td>
        <td>${p.price}</td>
        <td>${p.quantity}</td>
        <td>${p.price * p.quantity}</td>
        </tr>`))
}

return `
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<table class="table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Product</th>
<th class="w-20">Price</th>
<th class="w-20">Quantity</th>
<th class="w-20">Total</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

**// want to iterate below <tr>**
${allTr.join("")}
<tr>
<td colspan="3" class="text-right">Sub Total</td>
<td> ${p.subTotal}</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>`
}
```